# Bash script: Ouput missing from parallelized ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I run the following code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 30); do
{
        # output missing
        #ssh root@MYHOST "echo hi"

        # works
        #bash -l -c "echo hi"
        #echo hi
}&
done | wc -l
```

If I run ssh in parallel (30 times) and count the returning lines, I receive a random amount, always less than 30.
If I run `echo hi` in parallel (or within its own shell), I receive all 30 lines.

What is going wrong here?

P.S.: I know that there are other tools for parallelization like parallel or pssh, but I try to understand the problem described here.

Comment: Are you waiting long enough before counting lines?

Comment: yes, for two reasons: 1. If I don't use ```wc``` at all and count the lines by myself (whats printed on stdout) there are still some missing. 2. If I redirect the output to a file and count the lines of that I've got missing lines, too

Comment: What is your sshd_config MaxSessions? And might you be hitting that? Default is 10. A way to check might be do a short sleep inside the loop. Also check MaxStartups.

Comment: My ssh server gives error for some connections `kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`. So I get 23 or 25 or so. You don't have any error output?

Comment: `for ... do { ssh ... ; }& sleep 0.1; done | wc -l` works fine.

Comment: I can't test right now, but I have a strong feeling that it is the maxSessions. That value is default for sure. I threw away the debugging output, because I wanted to see stdout only, so that's on me too.. I will keep you posted and provide stderr as well tomorrow! Thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Doug Smythies, you provided the solution and thanks to you, too, pLumo, you posted the key error message.

I was in fact hitting `MaxStartups 10:30:60` where 10 is "Number of unauthenticated connections before we start dropping"
(Quote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812134/in-sshd-configuration-what-does-maxstartups-103060-mean)

The error message received when hitting that limit (which I threw away..) is
`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`.

Increasing the limit to 30 and restarting sshd resolves the issue.

Increasing `MaxSessions` to 30 did not have any effect. Neither negatively when `MaxSessions` was increased nor positively with the default settings for `MaxSessions`.

Thank you again! Resolving this showed me that I didn't do anything fundamentally wrong when I used parallelization. Now I can focus on the tasks I really want to parallelize :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. upvoted.